# Purpose of [tag:sex]

Tags: discussion, tags

In response to the comments on [Do either men or women have higher pain tolerance than the other?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/do-either-men-or-women-have-higher-pain-tolerance-than-the-other), should questions about the differences between men and women be tagged [sex](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex)? If not, is there a useful alternative? [gender](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) seems more apt for questions relating to *gender*; the opposing opinion was that [sex](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) is for the act of sex and not the biological distinction.

In any case, updating the [tag wiki](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tags/sex/info) with the appropriate expectation would be handy for newcomers such as myself.

Answer (score 13):

Personally I think [sex](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) should not be used at all in favour of

- [gender](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) for gender differences and gender issues (male/female/lgbt...)
- [sexuality](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality) for the psychological and social aspects of sex and sexual activities in general
- [reproduction](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reproduction) for the reproductive process, which may or may not include sex or even gender

Comment: Yep; that makes sense. [tag:sexuality] would apply to the linked question, ya?

Comment: @MrHen - I'd say "gender" would be a better tag - pain tolerance is not really sexuality related as a whole topic.

Comment: I propose "starfish" as a tag for reproduction related question that do not include sex/gender :)))